# How to remove clock from panel in gnome-shell?

Tags: gnome, panel, clock

How to remove clock from the top panel in gnome-shell?
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is possible by creating an extension.

```
mkdir -p ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/Disable_Clock@ocelot
cd  ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/Disable_Clock@ocelot
```

Make a metadata.json file.

```
gedit metadata.json
```

Cut following code, and Paste into the editor ,and Save.

```
{"shell-version": ["3.2"], "uuid": "Disable_Clock@ocelot", "name": "Disable Clock", "description": "Disable Clock from the top of panel"}
```

Make an extension.js file.

```
gedit extension.js
```

Cut following code, and Paste into the editor ,and Save.

```
const St = imports.gi.St;
const Main = imports.ui.main;

function init(meta) {
}

function enable() {
    Main.panel._centerBox.remove_actor(Main.panel._dateMenu.actor);
}

function disable() {
    Main.panel._centerBox.add_actor(Main.panel._dateMenu.actor);
}
```

Restart gnome-shell and Turn on "Disable Clock" extension by gnome-tweak-tool

Comment: Great! Thank you! Really good way with a possibility to turn it back easily. [For anyone else who might use this: I had to run gedit lines with sudo!]

Comment: Not working in 18.04

Comment: This worked for me in 18.04 - https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1110/hide-clock/

Answer (score 2):

Hide the clock in your current session with this command:

```
dbus-send --session --type=method_call --dest=org.gnome.Shell /org/gnome/Shell org.gnome.Shell.Eval string:'Main.panel._dateMenu.actor.hide();'
```

Comment: doesn't work in the latest versions of Ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

Press Alt+Right click the clock, there should be an entry saying *Remove from panel*.

Comment: Using Alt key while Right clicking clock doesn't seem to to anything, it just opens calendar like a simple Left click. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: That works in fallback mode with compiz disabled

Comment: Yes! Press the Alt first and right click on the clock and a popup will ask you for 'Remove' and 'Remove from panel' choose 'remove from panel and select 'Don't reload'. Try it again.

Comment: You actually need alt-super-right

Answer (score 0):

At teminal type the following:

```
sudo apt-get remove indicator-datetime
```

Comment: Removed indicator-datetime, rebooted system, clock is still there

Comment: @Laurynas seriously? I kinda want to remove the indicator now to see if your joking. The is really still there?